# type calculation in math expressions

Tags: java, types, type-conversion

I am prepare for ocpjp.

I know that:

```
byte * byte = int 

long * int = long
```

But I was wondered that `float * float = float`

float on float may be very huge number and for logically convert it to double.

Anyway for success exam passing I should to know all rules about it.

Please explain me these rules or just point to relevant jls part.

Comment: @halex yes. but if you want - you can clarify)) it would better

Comment: @Duncan ok I change it

Comment: @halex - sorry - bad english)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result of my investigation I created following rule:

```
if (statement contains double) 
   result-double
else if (statement contains float)
   result-float
else if (statement contains long)
   result - long
else 
    result - int
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose the relevant part of the JLS is [4.2.4 Floating-Point Operations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.4) :

> If at least one of the operands to a numerical operator is of type double, then the operation is carried out using 64-bit floating-point arithmetic, and the result of the numerical operator is a value of type double. If the other operand is not a double, it is first widened (§5.1.5) to type double by numeric promotion (§5.6).
>
> **Otherwise, the operation is carried out using 32-bit floating-point arithmetic, and the result of the numerical operator is a value of type float.** (If the other operand is not a float, it is first widened to type float by numeric promotion.)

So if you multiply two `float` values, a 32-bit operation is performed. An overflow to infinity will occur if the values are too large.

If you multiply a `float` by a `double`, the result will be a `double` and the `float` will be expanded to a 64-bit value during the operation.

Comment: **if you multiply a float by a long, the result will be a long** long num = 5l*4f;  it is compile error

Comment: @gstackoverflow Sorry, that was meant to say `double`!

Comment: **Sorry, that was meant to say double!** - I didn't understand this message

Comment: @gstackoverflow See the last paragraph of my answer. I edited since you made [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24077680/type-calculation-in-math-expressions/24077939?noredirect=1#comment37131804_24077939). Is there any part of my answer that still confuses you? I think it addresses your original question..